# How to use MySqlDate in SSRS report?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In **MySql** Date column format is **"yyyy-MM-dd"**

When I try to load it on report I got **#Error**

I tried using **CDate** and set **Localization** - **Language** but still doesn't work

What I'm using to fix this now is to use **date_format** from **MySql** query like this

```
date_format(myDate,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

and when I use **myDate** in **SSRS** report I have to convert it by using **CDate**

I'm just curious to know there is anyway better?